# How to get pull requests programmatically from TFS/Azure DevOps?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request

I want to make a C# application which notifies the user, when a new pull request comes in. Therefore I need a way to check for pull requests (in an interval). I looked at the TFS Api documentations, but couldn't find what I was looking for.
Can somebody tell me if this project is actually doable and could direct me into the right direction?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the built-in notifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops-2019#supported-subscriptions?

Comment: Because the built-in notifications only send an email and most colleagues don't frequently look into their mails. So I wanted to make a tool, which shows a little pop-up or something to make the user more aware.

Comment: @riQQ There are many causes, one of them is, if we are in a hybrid cloud and want to send Pull Request notification from the client's DevOps to vendor Outlook mailbox.

Comment: I have vote up @KBLY

Comment: Yes, @KBLY I did vote up for your question. Your question is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an application that periodically checks for pull requests, you can subscribe to a service hook that handles the "Pull request created" events. You can register predefined apps that are notified or create one of you own that provides a web hook and reacts to the event with custom code.

This way, you get a push notification instead of pulling over and over again.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops) for an overview, this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) for implementing a custom WebHook.

Comment: What if, we don't want to use pre-defined applications? In that case, we have to write code.

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use a pre-defined app you can create a custom WebHook that is notified when an event occurs. You could create an application for that or create an Azure Function that contains the code that should be executed if an event occurs. Maybe the application that should be notified supports WebHooks. In this case, you don't have to write code.